# Why Phenyl Carbocation is unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

Phenyl carbonation is said to be unstable because the + charge on it cannot be stabilized by Resonance or any other electronic effects, so my question is that if the resonance occurs in the direction shown in the below picture the + charge can be delocalized to some extent, so will it adapt that ?

[image: Phenyl Carbocation]

Comment: see the description of the phenyl carbocation in [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/benzene-halide-sn1-reaction/15410#15410)

Comment: The carbocation is orthogonal to the pi system

Comment: Those are valid resonance structures that you've drawn.  They correspond to  the charge-separated resonance structures one can draw for benzene.  Since they involve charge separation, they contribute little to the description of the aromatic pi system.  Further, the pi system is orthogonal to the empty $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital, consequently such resonance structures provide little, if any, stabilization of the cationic center.

Comment: I disagree with your first statement that it cannot be stabilized by any electronic effect because electron donating groups could make it more stable than before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your resonance structure doesn't do anything to stabilize the cation. You've created a singlet carbene at the top most carbon, so it has both the cation and the anion on the same carbon. These do not cancel out. As drawn, you have two hydrogens on the top carbon. You need to replace it with a single lone pair and an empty orbital.

Comment: Except for the fact that this is an inverse singlet carbene with the hybrid orbital being empty and the p orbital being populated … very interesting to think about the compound! =D

Comment: By the way, why would anybody downvote this (correct) answer?

Comment: @Jan Yeah, filled p orbital doesn't exist since it's really the resonance structure, but you're right that this is unusual.

Comment: I don't see it as a "singlet carbene at the top most carbon".  It is a series of charge-separated resonance structures of benzene which don't really contribute much to the overall description of the aromatic system.  Further, as I  pointed out in [my earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/benzene-halide-sn1-reaction/15410#15410), the aromatic pi system and the unoccupied $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital are orthogonal. Consequently there is not much, if any, interaction between them.

Comment: @Zhe thanks for clearing my doubt. You are right , even if the bond breaks in the direction shown carbon is left with an unfilled octet.