# Does Wurtz-Fittig-reaction involves Sn1 or Sn2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Following mechanism is commonly proposed for the Wurtz-Fittig-Reaction:

[image]

*[Picture from Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurtz-Fittig-Synthese#/media/File:Wurtz-Fittig-Synthese_Mechanismus.svg)*

The red marked reaction steps is a nucleophilic substitution (S<sub>N</sub>). I suppose that this is a S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction, with an intermediate carbocation, rather than a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction. In my opinion the resulting carbocation is good enough stabilized throughout the aromatic ring and therefore S<sub>N</sub>1 should be preferred, moreover because of the steric hindrance of the aromatic ring.

Is this assumption right? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I’m kind of torn between upvoting this question because you actually thought about it and downvoting because your thoughts are entirely in the wrong direction. Notice that the phenyl cation is **not** stabilised by resonance and **not** delocalised over the ring. Quite contrary to your expectations, it is very reactive.

Comment: @Jan Ok thanks, the orientation and type of the orbitals I totaly forgot. [This article](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/benzene-halide-sn1-reaction?noredirect=1&lq=1) explains this problem further. Therefore it cannot be a Sn1. 
But a Sn2 neither (massive steric problems). 
So I  assume that there is a total different mechanism. Maybe nevertheless a formation of a Phenyl cation, but through a different mechanism (abstraction the Br as a Bromid through the carban-Anion)?

Comment: My best guess is that it’ll be akin to an $\mathrm{S_NAr}$ reaction.

Comment: Note that the picture you linked to isn't present on the corresponding [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurtz%E2%80%93Fittig_reaction) as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Aryl carbons cannot go through SN1 nor SN2 substitution reactions. SNAr involves the creation of benzyne intermediate. The mechanism is this:

[image]

The benzyne has sp hybridized carbons, which should be linear, but forced to be bent. Therefore it can be attacked by a nucleophile, and become sp2 which isn't linear.

Notice that the carbanion can also attack the adjacent carbon. It's a special phenomena for this type of reaction. The mechanism was confirmed by carbon-14 labeling (Organic Chemistry/Paula Bruice, sixth edition, page 692).

Comment: "The mechanism was probably confirmed by carbon-13 labeling." You should have a source for this, imo - otherwise it just sounds like speculation.

Comment: I added a source.

Comment: Correct me if this is wrong, but isn't this the mechanism for elimination-addition of benzene, not $\ce{S_NAr}$?

Comment: The title of page 690 is: "Nucleophilic Aromatic Substitution: An Addition-Elimination Mechanism", and in page 691 it clearly says that this type of reaction is called SNAr ("the reaction is called an SNAr reaction" [substitution nucleophlic aromatic]"). In page 692 the title is "Nucleophlic Aromatic Subsitution: An Elimination Addition Mechanism That Forms A Benzyne Intermediate". It's simply a unique case of SNAr.